# Issues with using argparse with listcomprehensions

Tags: python, argparse, pytables

I'm using list comprehension to find specific datasets within a PyTable. However when trying to combine with arguments from argparser it returns no values.

Here is the section of code:

```
if args.Scount:
    print args.Scount, args.Scount[0], args.Scount[1]

    print 
    print [row['GRBname'] for row in table.iterrows() if args.Scount[0] <= row['SCounts'] <= args.Scount[1]]
    print

    print [row['GRBname'] for row in table.iterrows() if 0 <= row['SCounts'] <= 10]
```

Where `args.Scount` comes from:

```
parser.add_argument("--Scount", nargs=2, help="Used to display GRBs within the specified spectral count range")
```

So for example if I give --Scount 0 and 10:

First line prints `['0', '10'] 0 10` (this was just a test to check args had a value)

Second line prints `[]`

Third line prints a list containing the selected `row['GRBname']` within the `row['Scount']` condition.

If I switch back to standard loop structure I get the same results, though searching through pytable, argparse and list comprehension documentation hasn't helped me on this specific problem.

Comment: What is your question specifically? You have regaled us with your observations, but what do you want to know?

Comment: table.iterrows() seems like an iterator, it might be exhausted by the second call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing strings with integers; this may work in Python 2.7 but numbers are always considered 'smaller' than strings (sorted before strings).

You also should not compare strings with strings if you expected numerical comparisons. `'9'` is greater than `'10'` because `1` sorts before `9` (strings are compared lexicographically):

```
>>> '1' < 9
False
>>> '9' < '10'
False
```

Ask `argparse` for integers:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--Scount", nargs=2, type=int,
    help="Used to display GRBs within the specified spectral count range")
```

and convert `row['Scount']` to an integer too if it isn't already:

```
[row['GRBname'] for row in table.iterrows()
 if args.Scount[0] <= int(row['SCounts']) <= args.Scount[1]]
```

Comment: sigh, it's always the silly mistakes which i never seem to catch. 

adding type=int worked perfectly, thankyou